# Android: Полупрозрачный фон в виде картинки

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, background

Имеется заголовок NavigationView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_header_height"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/navigation_header_image">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_header_profile_image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_header_profile_image_size"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/navigation_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/navigation_header_horizontal_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_header_image"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/navigation_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/navigation_header_horizontal_spacing"
        android:text="MoS"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/navigation_header_horizontal_spacing"
        android:text="mos-webmaster@mail.ru"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Нужно задать фон в виде картинки с прозрачностью 50%, но чтобы при этом все дочерние объекты были без этой прозрачности. Как это сделать?
В разметке выше добавил в `LinearLayout` добавил саму прозрачность `android:alpha="0.5"` и изображение для фона `android:background="@drawable/navigation_header_image"`, но при таком раскладе все дочерние объекты на половину прозрачны. Может фон разместить в виде `ImageView`, а на нем уже остальные объекты?

Comment: сделайте прозрачным сам цвет в @drawable/navigation_header_image

Comment: именно саму картинку?

Comment: а это картинка сори, не так понял, сейчас отвечу

Answer (score 2):

```
//Drawable myImg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.navigation_header_image);


Drawable myImg = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.navigation_header_image);
```

Устанавливаем прозрачность

```
 myImg.setAlpha(128);
```

Устанавливаем background

```
main_layout.setBackground(myImg);
```

только id дайте вашему layout, к примеру:

```
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
```

Comment: метод `getDrawable()` устарел!
метод `setBackground()` не используется ниже 16 API.

Comment: не проще тогда будет фоновую картинку уже прозрачную подготовить?

Answer (score 0):

В качестве корневого макета используйте **ConstraintLayout** или что-нибудь еще, что позволит *размещать вью с наложением*. Потом в начале этого макета разместите любой макет, который будет служить фоном. И после него разместите макет со всеми вашими вью элементами.

Должно получиться что-то подобное.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/background_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/foreground_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Так в первом "фоновом" макете, вы сможете установить на фон картинку/цвет и настроить их прозрачность. Это никак не повлияет на вью элементы расположенные в другом слое.